# C++ Rest SDK Android Visual Studio 2015

Tags: clang, visual-studio-2015, casablanca

I'am developing an Android static library with Visual Studio 2015.

I'am using C++ Rest SDK (https://www.nuget.org/packages/cpprestsdk.android/). It works with Visual Studio 2015 RC but not with Visual Studio 2015.

The reason is that Visual Studio 2015 uses the compiler clang 3.6 and the SDK is compiled with clang 3.4.

Is there a way to use C++ Rest SDK with Visual Studio 2015?
Is there a way to install clang 3.4 into Visual Studio 2015?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved with the 2.7.0 release of C++ REST SDK.
https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/releases/tag/v2.7.0